# Trying to mutate the initialState using an AsyncThunk?

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit

I have an issue with not being able to mutate the state of the slice using the async thunk.

If I try using the ThunkAPI.dispatch or try to dispatch the reducer in any way in that async thunk, but it says that the reducer does not exist.

Here's some dummy code:

```
export const login = createAsyncThunk(
"login",
  async ({ username, password }, thunkAPI) => {
    try {
      const data = await login(email, password);
      getUserData(data.jwt).then(
        (response) => {
          thunkAPI.dispatch(setXState(response))
        }
      )
      console.log(data, 'data')
      return { user: data };
    } catch (error) {
 ...

}
```

}
);

Do you know if there's a way(because I can't find it on google atm) to do so?